# angular ng-repeat and html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have the next div in index.html:

```
...
<div ng-include src="'templates/blocks.html'" ng-controller='Foo'></div>
...
```

The Foo controller holds an array of html snippets under the "bars" property.

The blocks.html looks like:

```
<div class="block" ng-repeat="bar in bars">
        <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="{{bar}}"></div>
</div>
```

and what I'm getting is the html as text in the div with class "block", meaning it is not evaluated as html.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-bind-html-unsafe is removed in 1.2. Use ng-bing-html instead and remove the curly braces just like Sebastian said.

Include ngSanitize module as a dependancy to your app and dont forget to include its JS 
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular-sanitize.js.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the curly braces in `ng-bind-html-unsafe` and it should work:

```
<div class="block" ng-repeat="bar in bars">
  <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Just for completeness - here is a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B293X/1/).

Comment: thanks. I've also needed to remove the -unsage as user1429007 mentioned.

Comment: ng-bind-html-unsafe is depraceted

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in tree" ng-include="'a.html'" class="node"></div>
```

a.html

```
<p>  {{item.name}}</p>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.tree = [
                              {name: 'Узел', nodes: [] },
                                {name: 'Морской', nodes: []},
                                {name: 'Устричный', nodes: []}

                        ];
```